# MysqlWorkbench PostgreSQL Driver

Tags: macos, postgresql, mysql-workbench

I try to install PostegreSQL Driver but it doesn't work it get this exception when i run : ./configure --with-iodbc --enable-pthreads

> checking for iodbc-config... no  configure: error: iodbc-config not
>   found (required for iODBC build)

I followed this to install : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-postgresql-drivers-osx.html

I downloaded the latest version of mysqlworkbench , Xcode6.4 and components tools as it's specified.

I downloaded psqlodbc-10.00.0000.tar.gz

Hope someone could help, it's look really complicated to install a simple driver ... :(

Answer (score 5):

Save yourself the hassle (I tried to compile this and sorting out the compiling dependencies was a huge pain). Just install a precompiled driver using [Brew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install psqlODBC
```

Comment: This will not work, as @Mathieu specifically wants to use the `--with-iodbc` flag to build the driver for the **iODBC** software. Your [`brew install psqlODBC`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/psqlodbc) suggestion only builds the default driver for **unixODBC** software. Until somebody uploads a brew formulae with the iODBC flag enabled, brew is not a compatible solution.